# Multiple Achievement Notifications for the same thing

Tags: support

I keep switching between various SE sites today and I keep getting notified that I earned the yearling badge for being on meta.so see the screenshot: 
[image: Achievements Problem]

I think this could possibly be a bug with how achievements are viewed.

Comment: That's because you actually earned 3 yearling badges, not because the same notification keeps being repeated. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happened when meta.stackoverflow.com was split out into a meta for Stack Overflow (and a meta.stackexchage, for the whole network), becoming a **regular** child meta, inheriting reputation and users from its parent site.

Looks like you were on Stack Overflow for 3 years, so the badge system on meta.stackoverflow caught up.